# What's the equivalent of Excel's MINVERSE in Python / numpy

Tags: python, excel, numpy

I'm converting a client's Excel equation into a Python script and they use `MINVERSE`, `TRANSPOSE`, and `MMULT`. `transpose` and `dot` handle those in numpy but I can't seem to find a `MINVERSE` type function. The array I'm working with looks like this:

```
array([[Decimal('0.00001937974193760863606765660052'), Decimal('0E-32'),
        Decimal('0E-33'), Decimal('0E-32'), Decimal('0E-33'),
        Decimal('0E-32'), Decimal('0E-33'), Decimal('-0E-35'),
        Decimal('0E-34')],
       [Decimal('0E-32'), Decimal('0.00001881570399319161379416374436'),
        Decimal('0E-32'), Decimal('0E-32'), Decimal('0E-33'),
        Decimal('0E-33'), Decimal('0E-33'), Decimal('0E-36'),
        Decimal('0E-34')],
       [Decimal('0E-33'), Decimal('0E-32'),
        Decimal('0.00002155088649394313957212468752'), Decimal('0E-32'),
        Decimal('0E-32'), Decimal('0E-32'), Decimal('0E-32'),
        Decimal('0E-34'), Decimal('-0E-34')],
       [Decimal('0E-32'), Decimal('0E-32'), Decimal('0E-32'),
        Decimal('0.00002308127083915646134802447962'), Decimal('0E-33'),
        Decimal('0E-33'), Decimal('0E-33'), Decimal('0E-34'),
        Decimal('0E-34')],
       [Decimal('0E-33'), Decimal('0E-33'), Decimal('0E-32'),
        Decimal('0E-33'), Decimal('0.00002310448983055357325172035711'),
        Decimal('0E-32'), Decimal('0E-32'), Decimal('0E-34'),
        Decimal('-0E-34')],
       [Decimal('0E-32'), Decimal('0E-33'), Decimal('0E-32'),
        Decimal('0E-33'), Decimal('0E-32'),
        Decimal('0.00004672586580873250052060527969'), Decimal('0E-32'),
        Decimal('0E-34'), Decimal('-0E-34')],
       [Decimal('0E-33'), Decimal('0E-33'), Decimal('0E-32'),
        Decimal('0E-33'), Decimal('0E-32'), Decimal('0E-32'),
        Decimal('0.00001445780451042951889148457730'), Decimal('0E-34'),
        Decimal('-0E-34')],
       [Decimal('-0E-35'), Decimal('0E-36'), Decimal('0E-34'),
        Decimal('0E-34'), Decimal('0E-34'), Decimal('0E-34'),
        Decimal('0E-34'), Decimal('0.000001880009405810659923357817901'),
        Decimal('0E-34')],
       [Decimal('0E-34'), Decimal('0E-34'), Decimal('-0E-34'),
        Decimal('0E-34'), Decimal('-0E-34'), Decimal('-0E-34'),
        Decimal('-0E-34'), Decimal('0E-34'),
        Decimal('1.909353650093269872864190266E-7')]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `numpy.linalg.inv()` I think:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html

Note that you can't use this without casting your `Decimals` an actual numerical datatype. Basic mathematical operations will work because `Decimal` implements methods like `__add__` , but once numpy has to use a numerical algorithm you'll need a numeric datatype.

Comment: I tried that one (like this `np.linalg.inv(omega())`) but I get this and I'm not sure what it means `TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc inv`

Comment: I suspect the problem to be `Decimal` here, try casting to `float` (just for troubleshooting)

Comment: Yep this works `np.linalg.inv([
   [1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 1]
  ])` as it should. Huh, wonder how I can use decimals then :\

Comment: You probably can't without casting your decimals to actual an actual numerical datatype. Basic mathematic operations will work because `Decimal` implements methods like `__add__` , but once numpy has to use a numerical algorithm you'll need a numeric datatype. I'll edit this into the answer.

Comment: I'll google it, of course, but if you know off the top of your head (i'm new to Python) how do I do a type conversion from Decimal to float? Just doing a for loop and going one by one?

Comment: you can call `.astype(float)` on your numpy array